# Dividing one number by an array of numbers in R

Tags: r

2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the
numbers from 1 to 10 without any remainder. Use a loop to find out what is the smallest positive number that is divisible (we mean the remainder should be 0) by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?

So far for this I have the following code but it does not work:

```
divisors = seq(1:20)
divisors

num1 = 2520

while(TRUE){
    if (num1 %% divisors == 0){
      print(num1)
      break
    }
    num1 = num1+ 1
}
```

Also I need help with computing probabilities in R, 
How many draws in average you need to have one level A prize? To do this, please generate 1000 games and use a vector to record the number of draws.
For this I have the following code:

```
set.seed(1)
random_games <- sample(c('A','B'), size=1000, replace=T, prob=c(0.2,0.8))
random_games
```

What’s the probability to obtain the a level A prize within 5 draws? Calculate the theoretical value.
This one I am confused on how to calculate.

Comment: I get zero as an answer using that, which is not correct, the right answer is 232,792,560

Answer (score 1):

When you check the remainder for `1:20`, you get 20 booleans as a result - and you have to make sure they are all `TRUE`. You can do that using `all`.

```
divisors = seq(1:20)
divisors

num1 = 2520

while(TRUE){
  if (all(num1 %% divisors == 0)){
    print(num1)
    break
  }
  num1 = num1+ 1
}
```

or do

```
gcd <- function(x, y) {
  while (y) {
    z = x %% y
    x = y
    y = z
  }
  return (x)
}

Reduce(function(x, y) x * y %/% gcd(x, y), 3:20)
```

Comment: I did this, but it has been running for the last few mins with no number print out, is it because the program is too slow or is something wrong, if its too slow, how would I be able to speed it up?

Comment: @erocoar we can surely speed up this. Before even we get to rcpp. Only if we are talking of complicated things can we get to RCPP

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems the while loop does take ages to solve the problem, we will invoke recursiveness of the gcd and lcm:

```
gcd=function(x){
  w=1:min(x)
 max(w[sapply(w,function(y)all(!x%%y))])
}

lcm=function(x){
  if(length(x)>2) lcm(c(prod(x[1:2])/gcd(x[1:2]),x[-(1:2)]))
   else prod(x)/gcd(x)
}

 lcm(c(1:20))
[1] 232792560
```